# Compiling program using gfortran and the HDF-EOS2 library

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, hdf

I have the problem of linking the HDF-EOS library to a Fortran90 program. I have compiled the library from source to a directory specified in $prefix. My simple compile command is:

```
gfortran -I$prefix/include -L$prefix/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$prefix/lib -lhdfeos -lGctp -lmfhdf -ldf -lz -lsz -ljpeg tst.f90
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `gdopen_'
```

In the program, which I am not supposed to change, the HDF-EOS library is used via the external keyword, e.g.

```
integer(kind=4), external :: gdopen
```

In the library, **nm $prefix/lib/libhdfeos.a | grep gdopen** gives me:

```
00000000000120c0 T gdopen
```

When compiling with **-fno-underscoring**, I get just a different error:

```
gfortran -fno-underscoring -I$prefix/include -L$prefix/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$prefix/lib -lhdfeos -lGctp -lmfhdf -ldf -lz -lsz -ljpeg tst.f90
```

the error is then:

```
undefined reference to `gdopen'
```

Also, gfortran finds the libraries, otherwise it would complain. Is the error related to the underscore? What else can I try? I work on Fedora and gfortran version 4.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very likely to be caused by the underscore.

Try compiling with `-fno-underscoring` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html), but fixing it by a proper `bind(C)` interface would be better.

[This tutorial](http://www.hdfeos.org/examples/fort_grid.php) (Did you read it before going here? Very easy to find even for a complete novice in the library, like me.) also states you should use `-fno-underscoring`.

Continue by implementing the rest what the tutorial recommends, including compiling with `FC=$(HDF4_DIR)/bin/h4fc`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that in the question, I tried it, but with no success, I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: @Andre BTW, "gfortran finds the libraries, otherwise it would complain" is completely false.

Comment: Yes I did, it didn't help me, then I moved on and eventually came here. Shouldn't gfortran complain if I use -lhdfeos and it is not able to find a libhdfeos.a file?

Comment: The linker should complain, but that is after the compilation by gfortran is finished. But you do not specify `libhdfeos.a` in your example, it could also be using a dynamic library.

Comment: Ok, I thought I was doing that by adding the -lhdfeos parameter.

Comment: Yes, you were, but it could also link a dynamic version of the library, if it exists. It shouldn't change much though.

Comment: I was using this FC=$(HDF4_DIR)/bin/h4fc example to come up with the gfortran command line, it is a tool that basically gives you a proper gfortran command.

Comment: Rgr., it would help next time to describe more thoroughly in the question what you have tried.